# Pandas JSON to CSV replacing value issue

Tags: json, pandas, csv

I'm new to Python and couldn't find an answer to my questions (I may be wording it wrong though).

I am converting a JSON file to CSV file. The file that has one of the column values as **[999-999-9999]** but I need to remove the brackets on each end. I researched and found I can use re.sub, but had to use str() on my data set, since without using str() the data would keep the brackets. However, now it won't save the output file to csv anymore. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image: CSV File Output without re.sub function]

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\RKM\Documents\json_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['value'])
df_clean = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", str(df))
df_clean.to_csv(r'C:\Users\RKM\Documents\output_file.csv', index=False, na_rep="NULL")


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[146], line 10
      8 df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['value'])
      9 df_clean = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", str(df))
---> 10 df_clean.to_csv(r'C:\Users\RKM\Documents\output_file.csv', index=False, na_rep="NULL")

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I tried without using str(dt) and just dt, but it wouldn't remove the brackets from the output csv file. I expected it to be removed, so tried str(dt), but now it gives me the error of 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.

**Edit to Add:**
I updated the code to below. I treid pd.DataFrame and .to_frame(), but it says:
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not propertly called!

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\RKM\Documents\json_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

base_df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path =['value'])
base_df_clean = re.sub(r"[\([{})\]]", "", str(df))

#df = base_df_clean.to_frame()
df = pd.DataFrame(base_df_clean)
print(df)
df_clean.to_csv(r'C:\Users\RKM\Documents\output_file.csv', index=False, na_rep="NULL")
```

Comment: when you are doing `str(df)` you are converting your dataframe to a string. Hence, when you are calling `df_clean.to_csv`, you are getting an Attribute error since it is not a dataframe anymore. You need to convert `df_clean` to a dataframe to use `.to_csv`.

Comment: Updated original post at bottom with my reply about trying to convert to dataframe.

Comment: You cannot directly pass the string `base_df_clean` to `pd.DataFrame` as it does not take strings directly as input. You need to convert that to a dictionary or split the string when converting it to a dataframe. Please include what is inside `base_df_clean`, to get more specific answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an assumption as no sample data was given you can use .explode():

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "businessPhones": [["999-999-9999"], ["111-111-1111"]],
    "displayName": ["user1234", "user4567"],
    "givenName": ["joe", "mike"]
}
base_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data).explode("businessPhones")
print(base_df)
```

Output:

```
  businessPhones displayName givenName
0   999-999-9999    user1234       joe
1   111-111-1111    user4567      mike
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is exactly what I needed! I will add this to my notes, I appreciate it!